# How to read a CSV file using LabVIEW?

Tags: csv, labview

I am trying to read a CSV file generated by an oscilloscope (Tektronix TDS1001B).

The data in the file is very complicated and using a lot of commas.
Does anyone knew how to use the same "wizard" or where can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely just use the Read Delimited Spreadsheet (in the File IO palette) and set the delimiter to be a comma.